# Creating an assigning an object in c++

Tags: c++

Hello I am new to c++,

I can create an new instance of an class using `Example example("123")`

I have two question

1. I know we cannot check if the object is null like `if(example ==NULL)` because this is not an pointer do we have any other way to do that.
2. I have a method to return the object like: How can i return a null?

   ```
   Example get_Example() {
       if (example.getName().empty() {
           Example example("345");
           return example;
       }
       return NULL // i cannot return null.
   }
   ```

Can I do something like this?

```
Example get_Example() {
    Example example;
    if (example.getName().empty() {
        example = Example example("345"); 
        return example;
    }
    return NULL // i cannot return null. How 
}
```

`example = Example example("345");` I know this is stupid But how can i do that without pointer.

Comment: `Example *ex = NULL`.

Comment: @gongzhitaao Can u please read the question fully i know we can do it using pointer

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you want to achieve

Comment: Do _not_ use pointers as a `C++` beginner.

Comment: You're basically thinking about things as though it were Java. It's not. `example` is not some reference to a `Example` object. It denotes the object itself. The object itself cannot be null in the same way that a Java reference can be null.

Comment: Not being able to create an object is usually an exceptional state - consider throwing an exception to express (and handle) this.

Comment: @sftrabbit True i am from JAVA ... Okey i agree the object cannot be null do we have a workaround for the above method?

Comment: Your function could return a `boost::optional<Example>` (or soon `std::optional<Example>`.

Comment: A stupid question: Why can't you use pointers? Pointers are one of the lifelines of C and C++. The only alternative would be an 'invalid value' in your class.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I disagree. Pointers are substantial in `C`. In `C++`, Objects and Containers are preferred and most projects can avoid (raw) pointers.

Comment: @stefan surely. and I certainly agree about avoiding pointers in standard-lib-based C++ programs (for some odd reason people like ganging the library with the *language*. they're NOT the same). But when someone needs a polymorphic behavior what possible good is telling some half-assed beginner "use a smart-pointer!" when they don't understand why a raw pointer is *dumb* in the first place, or even how one *works* ? For beginners they're like the $10 prostitute on the corner. The sooner you know about her the sooner you realize its smarter to just avoid her altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use pointers, `Example *ex = NULL`.
2. Construct a default `null_example` and overload the `==`

   ```
   Example e;
   if (e == null_example) {
       e.init();
   }
   ```
3. but you could just provide a `is_init()` function.

   ```
   Example e;
   if (!e.is_init()) {
        e.init();
   }
   ```
4. you `get_example` could be something like:

   ```
   void get_example(Example &e) {
        // method2 or method3
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think to C++ object as OOP or Java. Example is not a refernce. It is the object itself. It exist because it has been decalred.

Checking for null (or making it null) can make sense if you can define a "state" for that object that you define to be null.

bor example you can define an

`explicit operator bool() const` method and return true when the object members have values you define representing an "non empty example".

Checking for a null `Example actualexample`, at this point is just `if(!actualexample)`

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).  The Null Object Pattern basically allows yo to return a fully constructed object that you identify as null.

The example in the wikipedia article linked gives a good example of it in action:

```
class animal 
{
public:
  virtual void make_sound() = 0;
};

class dog : public animal 
{
  void make_sound() { cout << "woof!" << endl; }
};

class null_animal : public animal 
{
  void make_sound() { }
};
```

Remember doing something like creating a specific "Null Object" (ie defining a global `Example kNullExample;` somewhere) is not a good solution because if you ever assign it to another Example object (ie `Example newObject = kNullExample;`) you won't be able to identify the fact the object is no longer null.

Another option would be to store a boolean value somewhere in the object and write an "IsNull()" function.  This is only really a solution when you can't get your class to become virtual (mapping binary files, for example) or if you really can't afford the virtual table jump.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign NULL pointer in that way, because the return object is not a pointer. If you don't want use pointers, a posible option may be the use of a specific NULL Example object. What I mean is check with a custom attribute of this class if the object instance is what you consider NULL. May be you can use the empty string passed in the constructor:

```
exampleNull = Example example("");
```

and check the string attribute to validate your "null" object

But remember: NULL only can be assigned to a pointer type

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a method that returns a value, simply rewrite the operator `==`, and make a control there, so if you do `if(example ==NULL)` the overloaded method for the control will return the desired boolean.